# IntelliJ can't see Android SDK classes

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have problems From time to time with my ItelliJ Android projects. When I start up, IntelliJ will not recognize the Android classes, and shows compiler errros. The project dependencies look okay.

I have been using a work-around for this that involves setting up a new Android SDK in the project. This of course is not optimal, and now that fails as well.

Does anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved by file/invalidate caches. No Idea what breakes the environment.

Comment: This solution also worked for me after my project suddenly refused to make with the `"cannot find symbol ...` error for a class in a library project.

Comment: Strange. I still have no Idea what triggers the error.  I think the IntelliJ team is a little behind on the Android tools compared to Eclipse.

Comment: This was IDEA 11 CE, and the new Android integration work is quite good. Although it's possibly directly related to the Android facet, it seemed more like the Java "make" system in general.

Answer (score 0):

Plain invalidate and restart did not solve the problem for me. I had to delete conflicting libraries first. Here is what I did:

1. go to project structure screen
2. select libraries
3. delete all libraries with errors
4. go to file -> invalidate cache/restart.
5. choose invalidate and restart

I have to say that after the restart some libraries with errors returned back but the problem was resolved though!

[image]